# Is the material-ui custom touch event needed anymore? It breaks a lot

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've noticed that [material-ui](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/new) still depends [on a package](https://github.com/zilverline/react-tap-event-plugin) that seems to break with subsequent React updates from Facebook. They're even a little upset by this it seems judging by the tone.  It makes keeping up with React very difficult and may no longer be needed.

Are we sure this is even necessary anymore? Has the React team maybe improved it at this point?

Furthermore, has anyone tried a find and replace and rebuilt to test the performance of the standard event at this point?

I could probably do it and submit a pull request, I'd need to get the thing set up for dev though. I know this is not hard but I'm still learning NPM.

Let me know what you guys think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's still needed on master, but has been removed on the `next` branch. I'm not aware of alternatives, and removing it on master would be a painful breaking change, which we would prefer to avoid.

Comment: So basically it's removal is coming soon. I suppose I'll hard code my react version for now so it works. Do you guys have a time frame on the next release?

Comment: You can already use it by installing `npm@next`, and making the necessary code changes for the revised API, assuming the components you need are migrated, however expect possible breaking changes at each release.

One of the core team is already using it in production. There's no timeline for release - it depends on the frequency and quality of community contributions.